# Troubleshooting keras/tensorflow errors in R Studio

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

Getting keras and tensorflow set up using the R packages to even begin a trial mnist model fitting has been tedious. Where do I check for commonly occurring problems with these packages?

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and activated a 3.5 Python, started getting the keras and tensorflow packages from GitHub reps instead of CRAN, and made sure tensorflow 1.9 is the version being installed. (skipped the mnist data preparation in the code below)

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")

install_keras(tensorflow= "1.9")
install_tensorflow(version="1.9")
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)


model <- keras_model_sequential() 

model %>% layer_dense(units = 784)

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Detailed traceback: 
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\topology.py", line 258, 
in __call__
output = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 629, in __call__
self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 1120, in _assert_input_compatibility
if x.get_shape().ndims is None:
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/getting-started-with-deep-learning-using-keras-in-r/) it is due to the reticulate package.

Close all R sessions and run

```
devtools::install_github(“rstudio/reticulate”)
```

Comment: please extract snippets and quotes which would explain the answer from the external resources, and add them here. Each answer should be clear and external resources should be used only to help understand it, this helps StackOverflow to be resilient against external resources unavailability.